# Maven: Is it possible to upload a set of 3rd party jars to repository, which can then be referenced as a single dependency?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

We are using an internal Nexus Repository for third party jars which are dependencies in our applications.

I am starting a new project, and have a set of 4 third party jar files which I want to upload to Nexus, and then reference, ideally, as a single dependency (i.e. artifactId/version) from my project pom.xml.

These jars are always given together, never versioned separately, so having a separate artifactId/version combination for each jar is not useful.  Is it possible to upload all the jars into a single artifact/version folder in Nexus, and then to reference them as a single dependency in my Maven project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you refer to in your comment, you can create a pom file of your own that depends on the four jars you talk about. Then, release this to your local nexus. Once this is done, you can depend on it as a pom dependency, which will bring in the four libraries you want.

Comment: Does this require deploying each of the 4 jars as separate artifacts into the Maven Repository? i.e. run `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>` once for each of the 4 jars? (I can do that, it's just that I thought it would be neater and cleaner if they all lived in one Repository bucket...)

Comment: Yes, it would, but you'd only have to do this once. Each artifact would be installed with it's own, unique, packaging, group and artifact id. Your own group-id should be used on the POM project you're using to bring them all together. JBoss do something similar with the java EE libs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom property in the pom file to hold the version number, so that you can change the version once for all the dependencies.
For example:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Really, I don't want to list them as separate dependencies at all. I know there is a dependency of `<type>pom</type>` which can act as a container for mutlple jars. But I'm not sure how that works. And better, I just want to maintain these jars as a bundle.  I don't care at all about their individual names or identity.