# How can I include a set of jar's as a single dependency in Maven?

Tags: maven

I'm new to Maven.

I have a Mavenized project, with separate subfolders for my source code and my JUnit tests.

My problem is that the JUnit tests need a bunch of Axis2 libraries (axis2-1.6.2/lib contains 67 .jar files).

Q: How do I "import" these .jar's into my Maven build?  Must I physically download them to our Maven repository (and possibly create Maven metadata for each .jar)?

Q: Is there any way I can group all the Axis2 .jars together as one entry in my pom.xml, or will I need to add 67 separate `<dependency>` stanzas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should only use the direct dependencies to Axis2 and not all transitive dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: Is it possible to upload a set of 3rd party jars to repository, which can then be referenced as a single dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661856/maven-is-it-possible-to-upload-a-set-of-3rd-party-jars-to-repository-which-can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Axis2 maven artifacts:  [Axis2 maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2), although I don't know which you have to specify as direct dependents.

Comment: Hi - I was hoping there was some magic "group list alias" to avoid having a million different <dependency> entries in my pom.xml.  I wound up testing trial-and-error to determine the exact subset of jars I needed, and putting each of them in my pom.xml as a direct dependency.  I also wound up using a corporate Maven repo (instead of http://mvnrepository.com).  Thank you for the followup, and thank you for the help!

Comment: @FoggyDay - agreed.  The one piece of information lacking from the typical maven repo page is the minimal dependency list you need.