# How to add user defined library to maven dependencies in eclipse

Tags: maven

How to add user defined library as a maven dependency in my eclipse. i just have bunch of jars needed to add to create a webapp. so i just created a custom library

Comment: By "library" do you mean an Eclipse Library (like "Maven Managed Dependencies")? I don't think you want to add that into Maven. Just add the dependencies directly individually.

Comment: If too many, you could make your own POM to collect them and depend on that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661856/maven-is-it-possible-to-upload-a-set-of-3rd-party-jars-to-repository-which-can?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I also expected/hoped there'd be an easy, one-shot way to have Eclipse Maven add an Eclipse-defined User Library to its dependencies :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the dependency directly in the pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

or you can install the jar to your maven repository

```
 mvn install:install-file
 -Dfile=<path-to-file>
 -DgroupId=<group-id>
 -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
 -Dversion=<version>
 -Dpackaging=<packaging>
 -DgeneratePom=true

 Where: <path-to-file>  the path to the file to load
    <group-id>      the group that the file should be registered under
    <artifact-id>   the artifact name for the file
    <version>       the version of the file
    <packaging>     the packaging of the file e.g. jar
```

and then add the dependency to your jar.

Comment: i have some 200 jars to add.. instead of adding each dependency is their any way to add all at one stretch

Comment: if you cannot avoid this, i would write some script which creates the dependencies with system scope. Are those 200 jars all custom jars from other projects you cannot transform into maven projects?